# Flexbox flex-grow property not respected when flex item contains an input element

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to make a chat UI. First using the flex-grow property I divide the layout in 2 columns with a ratio 2/5 and then I divide those 2 columns in rows with a ratio 1/9 for the first column and 5/1 for the second one.
This is what I have when I haven't added the input elements to the HTML code:

https://codepen.io/thenr/pen/PoooyEN

```css
#chat {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 2em);
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#friends {
  flex-grow: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#messages {
  flex-grow: 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#searchfriend {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

#searchfriend input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

#friendslist {
  flex-grow: 9;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.friend {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#chatmessages {
  flex-grow: 5;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#writemessage {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <!-- friends -->
  <div id="friends">
    <div id="searchfriend">

    </div>
    <div id="friendslist">
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- chat -->
  <div id="messages">
    <div id="chatmessages">



    </div>
    <div id="writemessage">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I add the input elements to the HTML code the ratios I had set are not respected and the flex items containing those input elements make bigger, and I don't want that to happen. Same HTML code but with the input elements added:

https://codepen.io/thenr/pen/RwwweQN

```css
#chat {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 2em);
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#friends {
  flex-grow: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#messages {
  flex-grow: 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#searchfriend {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

#searchfriend input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

#friendslist {
  flex-grow: 9;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.friend {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#chatmessages {
  flex-grow: 5;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#writemessage {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <!-- friends -->
  <div id="friends">
    <div id="searchfriend">
      <input type="text" name="" id="searchtext" placeholder="Search friend...">

    </div>
    <div id="friendslist">
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>
      <div class="friend"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- chat -->
  <div id="messages">
    <div id="chatmessages">



    </div>
    <div id="writemessage">
      <form action="" id="formchat">
        <input type="text" name="msgtext" id="msgtext" autocomplete="off">
        <button id="msgsend">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set `flex-basis: 0` where ever you have used flex-grow or flex-shrink. This will make sure all the elements respect flex-grow. Unless you specify flex-basis, flex-grow is just a suggestion to the flex's child.

Comment: use flex:2 and flex:5 instead flex-grow:2/flex-grow:3 . then no need to deal with flex-shrink/flex-basis to readjust behavior

Comment: Is this gone be responsive?

Comment: @Dejan.S Yes it is

Comment: How would it look like in mobile/tablet?

Comment: @G-Cyr It seems that it works if I use the flex shorthand instead of flex-grow. If you want to add your comment as an answer you are welcome. Thanks

Comment: @Dejan.S Since a mobile screen will be too small to add both the friends list and the chat conversation, I have though about only showing one of them in the screen at the same time. But still haven't written the code to make it responsible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the flex shorthand  `flex:2` / `flex: 5` instead `flex-grow:2`  /  `flex-grow:5` .

It will avoid to have to set `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` too.